Как интерпретировать значение слова "Особенность"?
Возник вопрос о том, как правильно интерпретировать значение слова "Особенность" в задании ниже. У меня есть два варианта. Первый: понятие "особенность" использовано в значении "уникальность, неповторимость", т.е. ни у одного из других вида позвонков, кроме грудных, нет данной особенности. Второй вариант: под особенностью понимается какое-либо свойство, характеристика строения грудных позвонков, безотносительно каких-либо других видов позвонков, а следовательно, не исключая того, что это свойство может присутствовать у иных видов позвонков. Какой из этих вариантов верный, в рамках задания?
Задание
"Особенностью строения грудных позвонков является:
А) наличие тела позвонка
Б) наличие дуги у позвонка
В) наличие ямки на поперечном отростке"

Если что-то имеет особенность, то всегда относительно чего-то другого. Чего другого - зависит от контекста, но тут явно контекст - остальные виды позвонков. Поэтому однозначно первый вариант.

@user190920 У всех позвонков есть тело и дуга, огибающая спинной мозг. Особенностью грудных позвонков является наличие ямок для сочленения с рёбрами (ответ В).

Да, это не противоречит "первому варианту", а как раз подтверждает его. Читайте вопрос внимательнее, если не понятно, что значит "первый вариант"

Согласен, особенность - это понятие относительное и зависит от контекста. Вы выразились: "тут явно контекст - остальные виды позвонков". Однако, обратите внимание на слово "явно". Этот контекст может быть явным, очевидным лишь для ВАС, но, по существу вопроса, такого контекста нет, как и любого иного, относительно которого применимо понятие "особенность". Насколько мне известно, в психологии это называется додумыванием. Полагаю, по причине отсутствия контекста, понятие "особенность" может быть относительно чего угодно, что существует в мироздании.....

(продолжение вышесказанного) Может быть относительно иных позвонков, а может относительно яблок, к примеру. Таким образом, нельзя однозначно утверждать, что контекст - это другие позвонки. Что думаете на этот счёт?
